# Why can't I use drop_na on a tsibble?

Tags: r, tidyr, na, tsibble

MRE:

```
library(tsibble)
#> Warning in system("timedatectl", intern = TRUE): running command 'timedatectl'
#> had status 1
library(tidyr)

my_tsibble <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18388, 18389, 18390, 18391, 
                                             18392, 18393), class = "Date"), new_cases = c(1444, 1401, 1327, 
                                                                                           1083, 802, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), key = structure(list(
                                                                                             .rows = list(1:6)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                   "tbl", "data.frame")), index = structure("date", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "date", interval = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                     year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 1, hour = 0, 
                                                                                                                                                     minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
                                                                                                                                                     nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), class = "interval"), class = c("tbl_ts", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
drop_na(my_tsibble)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   date       new_cases
#>   <date>         <dbl>
#> 1 2020-05-06      1444
#> 2 2020-05-07      1401
#> 3 2020-05-08      1327
#> 4 2020-05-09      1083
#> 5 2020-05-10       802
```

In other words, starting from a `tsibble` and using `drop_na` to remove the last row, I got a `tibble`. This is annoying because in order to apply the forecasting methods in `fable` I need `my_tsibble` to be a `tsibble`. How can I remove the `NA` values without losing the `tsibble` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you *can* use `drop_na` on a `tsibble`; it's just that the resulting object is coerced to a `tibble` in the process. The reason for this is that `drop_na` is a generic function within the `tidyr` package. There is no method specified anywhere for handling a `tsibble` differently. Therefore `drop_na` only outputs tibbles or data frames. Another way to look at it is that `drop_na` has never heard of a `tsibble`, but it knows that it inherits from `tibble`, and treats it as such.

However, you can define a new S3 method, `drop_na.tbl_ts` to do the job for you:

```
drop_na.tbl_ts <- function(ts) tsibble::as_tsibble(tidyr:::drop_na.data.frame(ts))
```

So now `drop_na` works as expected:

```
drop_na(my_tsibble)
#> Using `date` as index variable.
#> # A tsibble: 5 x 2 [1D]
#>   date       new_cases
#>   <date>         <dbl>
#> 1 2020-05-06      1444
#> 2 2020-05-07      1401
#> 3 2020-05-08      1327
#> 4 2020-05-09      1083
#> 5 2020-05-10       802
```